# PowerShell Script To Make A Security Group In Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a script that currently makes groups in Azure AD when provided with a CSV that contains a display name and description. the CSV is formatted like so:

```
DisplayName, Description
Name1, Description1
Name2, Description2
Name3, Description3
```

The script works like so:

```
$Groups = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PathToCSVWithGroupsIWant\CSV.csv"

foreach($Group in $Groups){

New-AzureADSGroup -DisplayName $Group.DisplayName -Description $Group.Description

}
```

Is there any way to improve upon this to make it run more efficiently, or is there a better way for me to perform this task?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the -Parallel option but for this, you have to change the script a bit.

```
$Groups = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PathToCSVWithGroupsIWant\CSV.csv"

$Groups | Foreach-Object -Parallel {

New-AzureADSGroup -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -Description $_.Description

}
```

I can't test it in Azure to confirm if Azure supports the -Parallel, but you can give it a try :)